# Missing architectures in apklib with native code apklib dependency (android-maven-plugin)

Tags: android, android-maven-plugin

I have an apklib which includes 3 architecture lib: 
armeabi/lib.so
armeabi-v7a/lib.so
x86/lib.so

I m using this apklib as a dependency for other apk and/or apklib projects, but when building with maven-android-plugin my project just contain one architecture lib.

This has been reported on:
[maven-android-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20OpSys%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=429)

I m trying to find out a work around for having all architecture libs provided by my apklib dependency added to my apk final project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all architectures just add ndkArchitecture configuration onto your pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
  <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <sdk>
      <platform>${sdk.platform}</platform>
    </sdk>
    <ndkArchitecture>armeabi armeabi-v7a x86</ndkArchitecture>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But in order to work maven android plugin version must be: 3.8.2 (with maven 3.1.1)